# Can't SSH to localhost

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, timeout, openvz

I've spotted a problem on one of my openVZ Containers.
There is a tool running for managing git repositories on a server which needs to connect this server by SSH. That tool is running on the same container.

I checked that I can:

- connect to the container via SSH from external
- connect to the container via SSH from host node and other containers
- use SSH from the container to connect external, host node and other containers

The problem is, that I get a "connection timed out" whenever I am inside the container and try to connect to itself by using its FQDN, one of its IP Adresses or just by using localhost.

I checked my iptables. They are completly empty.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something is awry with accessing your loopback interface. Make sure that the SSH daemon is listening on all available IP's.

Comment: SSH is listening on all IPs. netstat -a shows: 

`tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN`